# What is the explanation for the standard algorithm for scheduling a seeded single elimination tournament?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assuming the number of teams is a power of 2, I understand what the algorithm is in the sense that I can write a short program to implement it, but I am uncertain as to what it does.  From what I have read, I believe that it has the following property: At any stage in the tournament, if all the higher seeded teams have defeated lower seeded opponents, then no team will be playing against against a higher seeded opponent than any lower seeded team.  Is that the case and, if so, how do you prove it? If not, what property does the algorithm satisfy?

---

joriki, I kind of see what you are saying, though I am not sure how to formalize it.  Suppose there are 16 teams.  Start by listing the seeds 1 to 16.  Next form sublists of length 2 by combining each team in the top half with a team in the bottom half.  Do this by starting at the ends and moving inward, giving (1,16), (2,15),...,(7,10),(8,9). This gives the initial matches in the tournament. Next combine teams in the top quarter with teams in the second quarter. Again moving from the outside inward, create sublists of length 4 - (1,16,8,9), (2,15,7,10),... Each list of 4 represents teams playing in the teams playing in the first two games.

One question that this suggests is how we would do the scheduling for a seeded single elimination tournament where there are 3 teams per game, maybe for a board game like Monopoly.  It seems the procedure would be similar.  If you have 27 teams, start by listing 1 to 27.  Then combine the first team with the last two teams, giving (1,26,27), (2,24,25),...,(9,18,19). Now continue this process of combining sublists at the start with sublists at the end. This generalizes for any fixed number n of teams per game.

Comment: You got lucky that I happened to look at this post again. If you want someone to be notified when you write to them, you have to either comment on a post of theirs or ping them in a comment thread that they've contributed to.

Comment: For the property you were interested, it doesn't matter which lower seeds you let the higher seeds play against, since we assume that the higher seeds win. I think the pairing from opposite ends of the list is done to give good chances to the people in the middle and prevent discontinuities in the chances. E.g. if you were to pair $(1,9),\ldots,(8,16)$, then seed $8$ would have the easiest game and seed $9$ the toughest one, just on account of being one seed lower.

Comment: For games with $n$ teams, that means that all that matters is that the top $\frac1n$ of the teams are properly seeded, and you can add the remaining teams according to other criteria. Your way of doing it preserves the above advantage of avoiding discontinuities in the toughness of the games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That property does indeed hold. You can prove it by induction. It holds trivially in the base case of a single round. In a tournament with $n+1$ rounds, if the higher seeds beat the lower seeds in the first round, you’re left with a tournament with $n$ rounds that’s scheduled exactly like the standard algorithm would have scheduled it and thus has the property by the induction hypothesis.